# Why is the value of Float32Array.length always 3?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I was reading [the Mozilla Developer Network docs on Float32Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array) when I came upon

```
Float32Array.length
Length property whose value is 3.
```

... why is always 3? I also noticed that prototype property of the same name overrides it.

Comment: I'd nearly think this is a religious question

Comment: @popovitsj I think he meant 42.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the constructor takes up to 3 arguments:

```
Float32Array(buffer [, byteOffset [, length]]);
```

Every function in JavaScript has a length property that will return the count of the named parameters it takes.

E.g.

```
function foo(a, b) {}
foo.length === 2; // true

function bar() {}
bar.length === 0; // true
```

Answer (score 7):

`Float32Array` is actually a function. You can check that like this

```
console.assert(typeof Float32Array === 'function');
```

And that function accepts three parameters. Quoting the signature from the same documentation,

```
Float32Array(buffer [, byteOffset [, length]]);
```

Quoting the [`Function.length` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length#Description),

> `length` is a property of a function object, and **indicates how many arguments the function expects**, i.e. the number of formal parameters.

That is why the `length` property of `Float32Array` is always 3.

Answer (score 1):

This is the length of number of parameters for the (object-) *function* `Float32Array`.

However, when you instantiate it `length` will represent number of indexes:

```
console.log(Float32Array.length);  // => 3, number of arguments

var a = new Float32Array(10);      // create an instance with 10 indexes
console.log(a.length);             // => 10, number of indexes
```